# Find generating function of a sequence if A(x) is generating function of sequence $a_n$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

Let $A(x)$ be generating function of sequence $a_n$. What's the generating function of $s_n=a_0+a_1+a_2+...+a_n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

- $A(x) = a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+\cdots$
- You want to find $a_0 + (a_0+a_1)x+(a_0+a_1+a_2)x^2+\cdots$
- How about $(a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots) + (a_0x+a_1x^2+\cdots)+ (a_0x^2+\cdots) +\cdots$?
- Can you factorise this? Can you simplify the factorisation?

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{A(x)}{1-x}$$

To prove it, write out $\sum_{n=0}^\infty s_n x^n$ as a double sum and interchange the order of summations.